Powershell script to delete printer copies with status "Not Connected"
I previously had a script that would run at startup and delete all Brother PocketJet printer copies using the following command:
WMIC Printer where "Name LIKE 'Brother *(Copy *'" Delete
Recently this command has stopped detecting the printers after they have been disconnected (these are local printers that are connected directly to the computer). I have tried the following command which also does not detect the disconnected printers:
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Printer | where{$_.name -like 'Brother PJ-723 (Copy%'} | foreach{$_.delete()}
If I run Get-Printer I get the following output which excludes the 14+ copies I have of the Brother PocketJet printers which can be seen in this screenshot
PS> Get-Printer

Name                           ComputerName    Type         DriverName                PortName        Shared   Publishe
                                                                                                               d
----                           ------------    ----         ----------                --------        ------   --------
OneNote for Windows 10                         Local        Microsoft Software Pri... Microsoft.Of... False    False
OneNote (Desktop)                              Local        Send to Microsoft OneN... nul:            False    False
Microsoft XPS Document Writer                  Local        Microsoft XPS Document... PORTPROMPT:     False    False
Microsoft Print to PDF                         Local        Microsoft Print To PDF    PORTPROMPT:     False    False
Fax                                            Local        Microsoft Shared Fax D... SHRFAX:         False    False
Adobe PDF                                      Local        Adobe PDF Converter       Documents\*.pdf False    False


Anyone have any other ideas on how I can detect and delete these printer copies that are in the "Not Connected" state using a PowerShell script?

Do you see the printers in the registry? gci HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers

The Get-WmiObject command is deprecated and not available in PowerShell Core (v6+). Might as well move to Get-CimInstance -ClassName now. What does $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString() report on your system?

I think they are in the registry.  Try removing from following : Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows x64\Drivers

@jdweng This would allow me to remove the print driver which I do not want to do as our users will still need to connect to these printers, just trying to clean up their connections list automatically

@lit I was not aware of this so thank you! I am running version 5.1.22621.2506 on my system but most of our user laptops will be running 5.1.19041.2364

Check the registry.   You may be able to remove the duplicates without removing the driver.

remove-printer *brother* -whatif

get-printer | ? printerstatus -ne normal

This might do it.
get-printer 'Brother *(Copy *' | ? printerstatus -eq offline | 
  remove-printer -whatif


This unfortunately did not work, get-printer doesn't list any of the offline printers even if I filter it by printer status.
